# How can I get the table name in a PostgreSQL trigger function?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, synchronization

I have a trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "trigger_deleteUsers"()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO "DeletedEntities" ("uuidKey", "dateCreated", "dateModified", "dateSynced", "username", "entityName")
         VALUES (OLD."uuidKey", OLD."dateCreated", OLD."dateModified", "dateSynced", OLD."username", 'Users');
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER "deleteUsers" AFTER DELETE ON "Users" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "trigger_deleteUsers"();
```

This works for the table "Users". Every time I delete a row from the "Users" table the database inserts a row with ("uuidKey", "dateCreated", "dateModified", "dateSynced", "username", "entityName") into the table "DeletedEntities" that I will use for syncing purposes later.

The above works. Here's my problem I have about two dozen tables. I know I need to CREATE TRIGGER on each table, but I don't want to have to create a custom trigger function for each table. The only thing that would change from first function above is the last value in the INSERT statement within the function; instead of 'Users' it would be "Ledgers", or "Journal", or whatever.

Within a PostgreSQL trigger function, how do I get the name of the table that the OLD row belongs too?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

TG_TABLE_NAME. See the docs for other trigger arguments: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: Just what I was looking for, just looked in the wrong place in the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
TG_TABLE_NAME::regclass::text
```

I use it with version 9.4 but it should be working from 8.4 up.

Here is your code with this change:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "trigger_deleteUsers"()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "DeletedEntities" ("uuidKey", "dateCreated", "dateModified", "dateSynced", "username", "entityName")
  VALUES (OLD."uuidKey", OLD."dateCreated", OLD."dateModified", "dateSynced", OLD."username", TG_TABLE_NAME::regclass::text);

  RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER "deleteUsers" AFTER DELETE ON "Users" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE 
PROCEDURE "trigger_deleteUsers"();
```

let me know if it helps!

Comment: Works on a Postgresql 12.2.