# Get Table Name in Event Trigger

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have an event trigger that executes on create, alter and drop table.

```
create event trigger CustomizeTable
   on ddl_command_end
   when tag in ( 'create table', 'alter table', 'drop table' )
   execute procedure CustomizeTable();
```

Within the procedure I want to create a trigger on the newly created table.

```
create or replace function CustomizeTable() returns event_trigger as 
$$
begin
      EXECUTE 'create trigger DoAudit after update on XXXXXX...
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

How can I get the table name within the event trigger?

I tried using **TG_TABLE_NAME** as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049815/how-can-i-get-the-table-name-in-a-postgresql-trigger-function) but it seems that this only works on non-event-triggers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to use the event trigger information functions described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-event-triggers.html#PG-EVENT-TRIGGER-DDL-COMMAND-END-FUNCTIONS).

For example, to get the name a newly created table, use

```
SELECT objid::regclass
FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands();
```

Comment: Oh I was at the 9.4 documentation of that site and just saw that it got extended starting with 9.5. Thanks for that.

Comment: @SergiyMatvienko I hear you, and I have added an example.