# How can I get the table name in a Oracle trigger function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

How can I get the table name inside trigger function?

Something similar to `TG_TABLE_NAME` in Postgres, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049815/how-can-i-get-the-table-name-in-a-postgresql-trigger-function)

Oracle 10g or above.

Comment: ora_dict_obj_name

Comment: Please describe what type of trigger you use. Triggers in Oracle are not the same as in Postgres: they are created "in place" and attached to the specific table, not by `create function... return trigger`, you have to write some code for *every* table. That's why you already know the object name when you start coding. For database/schema triggers you may use `ora_dict_obj_name` as said in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

That's `user_triggers` view (if I understood the question correctly).

```
SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    null;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> select trigger_name, table_name from user_triggers;

TRIGGER_NAME                   TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TRG_TEST                       TEST                 --> this is the one I've just created
TRG_AIUD_EMP                   EMPLOYEES

SQL>
```